# Please add an "other" option to the down vote mechanism of adverts

Tags: feature-request, advertising

Sometimes I feel the need to specify a different reason for downvoting an advert.

Please add an "other" option with a text box to optionally enter a reason.

> [image: other option please]

Comment: FYI: we're in the process of getting this added. I'll provide an answer once we have a better idea of ETA.